# Drop event not firing for canvas/StackPanel in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, drag-and-drop

**XAML**

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Canvas  x:Name="VideoCanvas" Width="800" Height="600" AllowDrop="True" Background="RosyBrown" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel Drop="VideoCanvas_Drop" AllowDrop="True" Name="CommandBar" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Beige" Height="39" Width="783" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="3">
                <Button Name="PlayMovie" Background="AntiqueWhite" Content="Play" FontWeight="Bold" Click="PlayMovie_Click" Margin="50,5,0,5" Width="100"/>
                <Button Name="PauseMovie" Background="AntiqueWhite" Content="Pause" FontWeight="Bold" Click="PauseMovie_Click" Margin="50,5,0,5" Width="100"/>
                <Button Name="VideoStop" Background="AntiqueWhite" Content="Stop" FontWeight="Bold" Click="VideoStop_Click" Margin="50,5,0,5" Width="100" />
            </StackPanel>
            <MediaElement x:Name="mediaEl" Canvas.Top="150" Width="800" Height="450" AllowDrop="True" AutoPlay="True" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

**C#**

```
private void VideoCanvas_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            DragEventArgs dr = e as DragEventArgs;

            if (dr.Data == null)
                return;
            IDataObject data = dr.Data;
            FileInfo[] file = data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as FileInfo[];
            if (file.Count() > 0)
                mediaEl.SetSource(file[0].OpenRead());
            if (mediaEl.CurrentState != MediaElementState.Playing)
            {
                mediaEl.Play();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag and Drop is not implemented by default in Silverlight. To use Drag & Drop functionality in Silverlight you have to use the DragDropTargets (PanelDragDropTarget, ListBoxDragDropTarget,...) from [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/).

**XAML**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Canvas  x:Name="VideoCanvas" Width="800" Height="600" AllowDrop="True" Background="RosyBrown" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <toolkit:PanelDragDropTarget AllowDrop="True" Drop="VideoCanvas_Drop">
              <StackPanel Name="CommandBar" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Beige" Height="39" Width="783" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="3">
                  <Button Name="PlayMovie" Background="AntiqueWhite" Content="Play" FontWeight="Bold" Click="PlayMovie_Click" Margin="50,5,0,5" Width="100"/>
                  <Button Name="PauseMovie" Background="AntiqueWhite" Content="Pause" FontWeight="Bold" Click="PauseMovie_Click" Margin="50,5,0,5" Width="100"/>
                  <Button Name="VideoStop" Background="AntiqueWhite" Content="Stop" FontWeight="Bold" Click="VideoStop_Click" Margin="50,5,0,5" Width="100" />
              </StackPanel>
            </toolkit:PanelDragDropTarget>
            <MediaElement x:Name="mediaEl" Canvas.Top="150" Width="800" Height="450" AllowDrop="True" AutoPlay="True" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

C#

```
private void VideoCanvas_Drop(object sender, Microsoft.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
        {
            DragEventArgs dr = e as DragEventArgs;

            if (dr.Data == null)
                return;
            IDataObject data = dr.Data;
            FileInfo[] file = data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as FileInfo[];
            if (file.Count() > 0)
                mediaEl.SetSource(file[0].OpenRead());
            if (mediaEl.CurrentState != MediaElementState.Playing)
            {
                mediaEl.Play();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Jehof,
Thanks for your quick reply. but sad is that it fires the event if i drag and drop any item from the stack panel itself but if I drop any media item from my desktop then it is not firing  the evnet .

Thanks again

Comment: Working fine in Mozilla 11.0 but not in IE 8 , chrome

Comment: I am crazy :(
it is working fine in IE 8.0.6001.18702 but not in IE 8.0.7601.17514.
Am I doing anything wrong ? if not then How silverlight is cross browser :(

Comment: which version of silverlight are you using? normally it has nothing to do which browser you use, cause silverlight has its own runtime and should work in each browser the same.

Comment: Ya , It should work for every browser .
I am using silverlight 4 runtime

Comment: reference missing for "toolkit"... I've added System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit and System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit but it doesn't convince the error..